# XSLT for UBL XML cannot find node values

Tags: xml, xslt

This XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Things>
      <Thing AutoReceive="True">
        <xsl:value-of select="Order/cbc:ID" />
      </Thing>
    </Things>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

against this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- 
    Unviversal Business Language 2.0
    http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/UBL-2.0.html
    http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Order-2.0.xsd
-->
<Order
  xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
  xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2"
>
  <!-- Mx Generated Order Number -->
  <cbc:ID>8343</cbc:ID>
</Order>
```

cannot find the node values.  I've tried a lot of variations and I've asked three other developers to look at it.  So far none of us can figure it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Things xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <Thing AutoReceive="True" />
</Things>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Order` is in a namespace too, so you must call it by a fully-qualified name - after assigning a prefix to the namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns:ord="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2"
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Things>
        <Thing AutoReceive="True">
            <xsl:value-of select="ord:Order/cbc:ID" />
        </Thing>
    </Things>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming you want the result to be in the `"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2"` namespace.

---

Note also that for the purposes of this example, these namespace declarations are redundant:

```
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
```